# Android: Textinput does not rise up in fullscreen mode inside a webview

Tags: android, html, webview, fullscreen, textinput

My Android APP has a webview to display html content, in one of the pages have text boxes, and when I click on the text box appears the Android keyboard, and the textbox show up to be visible, so far so good, but when I put the application in Fullscreen Mode, when I call the keyboard, textbox does not rise up.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: what do you mean by `when I call the keyboard` ?

Comment: Mean, When I click on textinput, normally the soft keyboard show and pull the textinput up, but in fullscreen mode, does not happens. Even when I remove the APP from fullscreen mode. After the application has entered at least once in fullscreen text boxes never rise up.

Comment: Anyone have more ideas?